# Use flip transition to switch between two view controllers

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, interface-builder

I have two view controllers `ViewController` and `SettingsViewController` (both with xibs) which I would like to switch between with the flip animation.

The code I have found so far is:

```
viewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
[self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

I am not sure how to apply this to the specific views I need. I am trying to declare the second view with:

```
SettingsViewController *controller = [[SettingsViewController alloc] initWithNibName: @"SettingsViewController" bundle: nil];
```

But this doesn't seem to work.

How can I declare the second view and then make the animation? Is the above code correct?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
yourViewController *yourController = [[yourViewController alloc] init];
yourController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
[self presentModalViewController:yourController animated:YES];`
```

Comment: You should indent by 4 spaces, then you get a proper code block with syntax highlighting. I would have edited your answer, but SO refuses because the change is < 6 characters.

Comment: @JSA986 Thank you, but which one do I replace with the actual name of my view controller SettingsViewController? yourViewController or yourController?

Comment: @samiles yourViewController is the name of your view controller, yourController is whatever you name it